# phaser/spine - play first animation just once when I play two animations continuously

Tags: phaser-framework, spine

```
var itemshop_idx = {
    idle:1,
    out:2,
    in:3
};

spine_itemShop.state.onComplete = function (trackIndex) {
        switch(trackIndex){
            case itemshop_idx.in://in
                spinePlay_1(spine_itemShop, "popup_item_shop_idle", itemshop_idx.idle, true);
                break;
            case itemshop_idx.out://out
                group_itemShop.visible = false;
                break;
        }
    };

spine_itemShop.setAnimationByName(itemshop_idx.in, "popup_item_shop_in", false);
```

this code show me "popup_item_shop_in" animation just once.
when I play

```
spine_itemShop.setAnimationByName(itemshop_idx.in, "popup_item_shop_in", false);
```

again, I don't show "popup_item_shop_in" animation. 
Just be showed "popup_item_shop_idle" animation directly.

what a problem?

I have searched solution about this problem use a lot of keyword like
spine/phaser/animation/pixi.js/orange group/github/time/replay/reset/init/etc...

But I can't find solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spine or the plug-in for Phaser, but to just clarify; are you talking about this plug-in? -> https://github.com/orange-games/phaser-spine

Comment: yes, I use it. Its version is 3.0.9